# pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: centos, vps, postgresql, dedicated-server

Im getting this error with postgre in my centos vps

> Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry
>   for host "::1", user "xxx", database "xxx_xxx", SSL off in

Here is my pg_hba.conf

```
local all all md5 
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

Everything seems right, but always get this error, no matter what user i create and set.

Answer (score 5):

> Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry
>   for host "::1", user "xxx", database "xxx_xxx", SSL off in

`"::1"` means that you're connecting via IPv6.

Either specify `-h 127.0.0.1` or add/uncomment an entry to/in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host all all ::1/128 md5
```

Comment: No, still not working with host all all ::1/128 md5 

Wha do you mean with Either specify -h 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: I mean `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U...`.